# C# EmguCV - Circle line thickness calculation

Tags: c#, geometry, emgucv

I want to Circle line thickness calculation like this below:

[image]

Which method can help me to do so?

Thanks for your reply David. I'm new to emgucv. So I do not know where I'll start. I can do the following image using canny edge. But I can not calculate distance, because I do not know what I would use the code. Which can I use code?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strFileName = string.Empty;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Load image
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(ofd.FileName);
        //Convert the img1 to grayscale and then filter out the noise
        Image<Gray, Byte> gray1 = img1.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
        //Canny Edge Detector
        Image<Gray, Byte> cannyGray = gray1.Canny(120, 180);
        pictureBox1.Image = cannyGray.ToBitmap();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would try to get bounding rectangles of the 2 circle contours and calculate the difference between their width or height. There are many ways to do this but you need to show some of your code so we can help you where you stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me Guide you a little bit further.

```
//load image
            Image<Gray, Byte> loaded_img = new Image<Gray, byte>(Filename);
            Image<Gray, Byte> Thresh_img = loaded_img.CopyBlank();

            //threshold to make it binary if necessaray
             CvInvoke.cvThreshold(loaded_img.Ptr, Thresh_img.Ptr, 0, 255, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_OTSU | Emgu.CV.CvEnum.THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY);
            //get contours of circle
             Contour<Point> Circle_cont = Thresh_img.FindContours();
            //get height & width of the bounding rectangle
             int height_Circle_1 = Circle_cont.BoundingRectangle.Height;
             int width_circle_1 = Circle_cont.BoundingRectangle.Width;

             Circle_cont = Circle_cont.HNext;
             int height_Circle_2 = Circle_cont.BoundingRectangle.Height;
             int width_Circle_2 = Circle_cont.BoundingRectangle.Width;

            //get ring thicknes in Px
             double ring_thickness_1 = Math.Abs(height_Circle_1 - height_Circle_2) / 2;
             double ring_thickness_2 = Math.Abs(width_circle_1 - width_Circle_2) / 2;
```

This should get you the thickness of your ring in Pixels. If you want it in cm you need to scale the Px value with the real Pixel length. I applied this code snippet to your example image and got 56 Pixel for both Thickness values.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help David. Your explanation was very helpful.